# given Sn, find a_n and sum of a_n

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am given $$s_n=\frac{n-1}{n+1}$$ find $a_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$

I use $a_n = s_n-s_{n-1}$ and got $$lim_{n->{\infty}}\frac{2}{n(n+1)}$$

Then the theorem says

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n= lim_{n->{\infty}}s_n$$

and the answer is 1 as n approaches infinity.

I also know that if I change $a_n$ into a telescope sum and solve it.
$$\lim_{n->\infty} \frac{2}{n}-\frac{2}{n+1}$$

it becomes $$\lim_{n->\infty}2-\frac{2}{n+1}$$

the answer is 2 as n approach infinity.

now, I don't understand why the two are not identical. did I make theoretical error with my reasoning?

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty} -s_0$

Comment: How do you do the step from the line above "it becomes" to the line below it? That is wrong, of course. What happened to $\;\frac2n\;$ in the expression above?! And why/how come you want to "telescope" ... a **sequence** ? You telescope *a series* !

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS What you wrote doesn't seem to make any sense...

Comment: He just means $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (\frac{2}{n} - \frac{2}{n+1}) = 1$, and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} s_n = 1$, it works well.

Comment: Notice that $a_n = s_n - s_{n-1}$ works only for $n \geq 2$. We have to compute $a_1$ separately, and this is simply $a_1 = s_1$. This is what other people are pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, $a_1 = s_1 = 0, a_n = \frac{2}{n} - \frac{2}{n+1} ,n \ge 2$, so there is no contradiction.

Comment: @ victor Chen  great, I just realized my foolishness of not realizing when n=1, the whole thing is 0, now it makes sense because by starting from n=2, it converges to 1. thanks.